# Trying to send this html into localstorage so I can use in a new cart page but it keep giving me an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, object

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="cofefe">
                    <img src="photos/Shop%20-%20French%2Roast.png">
                    <p>Somecoffee</p>
                    <p>15</p>
                    <p>French Roast</p>
                    <button id="cartitem1" onclick="addCart()" class="button">Add to cart</button>
                </div>
```

This is the javascript:

```
function addCart() {
        var name = this.parentElement.children[1].getContext;
        var prices = this.parentElement.children[2].getContext;

        var storeThis = {'name': name, 'price': prices};
        localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(storeThis)); 
    }
```

In the chrome I get :

> cart.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined
>       at addCart (cart.js:2)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (shop.html:40)

and

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined

I am sure there is something wrong with the javascript. I don't understand what.

Answer (score 2):

Your JavaScript code has nothing for `this` to work on. You need to get the current target. Change your function to the below:

```
function addCart(event) {
    var name = event.target.parentElement.children[1].getContext;
    var prices = event.target.parentElement.children[2].getContext;
    var storeThis = {'name': name, 'price': prices};
    localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(storeThis)); 
}
```

## EDIT:

Here's a failsafe way to make it work - use JavaScript to add an event listener rather than an inline HTML event listener:

```
<button id="cartitem1" class="button">Add to cart</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("cartitem1").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    addCart(e);
})
```

Comment: What is event object? 
isn't onclick the event?
I trried it and it gave me an error :
shop.html:40 Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (shop.html:40)

Comment: @Drearo I've fixed it, can you test it to make sure it works for you?